# iOS - standard insets for tableview cell separators

Tags: ios, swift, view, tableview, cell

as the title states, I'm wondering what the standard insets are for the default iOS tableview is. I'm using a different library and want to set the insets equal to the default table view cells.

Answer (score 0):

You can use insets property given in storyboard or you can give insets programmatically.

Like,

[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(108, 0, 0, 0)]; // Top, Left, Right, Bottom